# Is there any way to perform something alike std::bind in C?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

So I have a function of type `void (*actionOnM)( void * myTypeInstance)` and I need to wrap it into and pass as `void (*action)()`. Is such thing possible in C?

Comment: What is your problem with that ?

Comment: to be able to get a pointer to `actionOnM(data1)` ... `actionOnM(dataN)` at runtime (pointer that would look like `void (*action)()` ).

Answer (score 3):

You can generally translate (simple) C++ in C with the following rules :

- a C++ class becomes in C a struct containing only attributes (no methods)
- C++ methods are C functions taking a pointer to the object (here a struct) as first parameter

Here your data are :

- a pointer to a function taking a void * parameter and returning void
- a pointer to the parameter

But you will not pass it as a pointer to a function but as a pointer to the struct :

```
typedef struct _binder {
    void (*action)(void *param);
    void *param;
} binder;
```

When you want to *bind* `actionOnM(&myTypeInstance)` you just do :

```
binder *bind = malloc(sizeof(binder));
bind->action = &actionOnM;
bind->param = &myTypeInstance;
```

You can then pass the bound function as the single parameter `bind` :

```
void otherFunct(binder *bind, int otherParam) {
    /* ... */
    bind->action(bind->param); /* actual call to bound function */
    /* ... */
}
```

and later of course `free(bind)` :-)

If you want all that to be closer to the C++ way, just define an executor function :

```
void bind_call(binder *bind) {
    bind->action(bind->param);
}
```

Other function would then become :

```
void otherFunct(binder *bind, int otherParam) {
    /* ... */
    bind_call(bind); /* actual call to bound function */
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a wrapper function, and then pass a default parameter, presumably `NULL`, like

```
void action()
{
    actionOnM(NULL);
}
```

I believe in c++ it works if you set a default parameter for `actionOnM()`, so this emulates that.

Comment: Mainly idea is to be capable to bind a variable into function pointer (not NULL but any given, if possible not defined at compile time pointer)

Comment: @DuckQuen that is impossible in c, because in c++ the `std::bind` class might store the pointer somewher and then pass it to the function when it's called, but you can't do that in c, can you please give some context? who is taking the function pointer as a parameter?